# Regex get string inbetween a certain character

Tags: java, regex

```
|Location|Time|Type|Duration|
```

Let's say I want to extract the word `Time`, I have to get the string inbetween the second and the third '|'. I've looked up some regex patterns and applied them in Java, but I can only get the first word using this regex:

```
(?<=\|)[^|]++(?=\|)
```

Comment: Why are you using regex? Sounds easier to just use a `string.split("\\|")[2];`.

Comment: @Keppil `split` also uses regex :)

Comment: @Pshemo: I was waiting for that one. Not sure how to word it to avoid nitpicks though.

Comment: Yes, that is hard one. I usually write something like "maybe instead using regex to find proper element, use it to find delimiters and split on it".

Answer (score 0):

This regex captures Time in the first capture group:

```
(?:.*?[|]){2}\s*(\w+)
```

Please tell me that you aren't planning on assigning it to a variable named Bottle...